# Foreach loop to create 100 buttons, painting all buttons at same time as to prevent flicker

Tags: c#, button, controls

In my minesweeper game I need to dynamically create controls in order to shift between easy - medium - hard. Let's say for the sake of the question hard consists of 100 buttons.

This is how I'm creating them:

```
this.SuspendLayout(); //Creating so many things that I assume it would be faster to suspend and resume.
foreach (string i in playingField)
{

    Button button = new Button();
    button.Name = i;
    button.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Popup;
    button.Margin = new Padding(0);
    button.TabIndex = 0;
    button.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
    button.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
    button.BackgroundImage = blockImage; //##//
    button.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.GetUnderSide);
    button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
    minesPanel.Controls.Add(button); //Adding the controls to the container
}
this.ResumeLayout(); //Refer to above. Correct me if I'm wrong please.
```

As you can see I'm creating all of the controls through a for loop, and then adding them. It results in each button being painted once at a time. I also tried `name.Controls.AddRange(arrayButtons)` and it still resulted in the same problem. Individual painting.

What I need is a way to create all items, and then paint them ALL after, like painting a single bitmap with `DoubleBuffered`, but alas, that doesn't work either.

Furthermore, I have tried this:

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            // Activate double buffering at the form level.  All child controls will be double buffered as well.
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;   // WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Which kind of works. It only works on application startup. However, given that I will be changing grid sizes and adding more controls at runtime, it is not a viable option.

I've been told it's as easy as using the methods in the `Graphics` class. Problem is, I don't know where to start.

If anyone could provide some help on getting all my controls to be painted at the same time, that would be great.

Comment: Windows Forms ? SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() might help

Comment: I'm using ``SuspendLayout`` and ``ResumeLayout`` already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, WinForms does not like to have too many controls, especially when you get into the hundreds.  You can never have each control paint at the same time since each control will send its own paint message to windows.

I think the best way to approach a game board like MineSweeper is to just use one control and draw the grid of buttons.

Simple Mine class:

```
public class Mine {
  public Rectangle Bounds { get; set; }
  public bool IsBomb { get; set; }
  public bool IsRevealed { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a new control where you inherit from the Panel control and set the DoubleBuffered property to prevent any flicker:

```
public class MineSweeperControl : Panel {
  private int columns = 16;
  private int rows = 12;
  private Mine[,] mines;

  public MineSweeperControl() {
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.ResizeRedraw = true;

    // initialize mine field:
    mines = new Mine[columns, rows];
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {
      for (int x = 0; x < columns; ++x) {
        mines[x, y] = new Mine();
      }
    }
  }

  // adjust each column and row to fit entire client area:
  protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
    int top = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {
      int left = 0;
      int height = (this.ClientSize.Height - top) / (rows - y);
      for (int x = 0; x < columns; ++x) {
        int width = (this.ClientSize.Width - left) / (columns - x);
        mines[x, y].Bounds = new Rectangle(left, top, width, height);
        left += width;
      }
      top += height;
    }
    base.OnResize(e);
  }

  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {
      for (int x = 0; x < columns; ++x) {
        if (mines[x, y].IsRevealed) {
          e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkGray, mines[x, y].Bounds);
        } else {
          ControlPaint.DrawButton(e.Graphics, mines[x, y].Bounds, 
                                  ButtonState.Normal);
        }
      }
    }
    base.OnPaint(e);
  }

  // determine which button the user pressed:
  protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; ++y) {
      for (int x = 0; x < columns; ++x) {
        if (mines[x, y].Bounds.Contains(e.Location)) {
          mines[x, y].IsRevealed = true;
          this.Invalidate();
          MessageBox.Show(
            string.Format("You pressed on button ({0}, {1})",
            x.ToString(), y.ToString())
          );
        }
      }
    }
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's clever... I'm liking this. Now to see if I can wrap my head around the code.

Comment: Alright, I made a pastebin trying to understand the code since it's too long to post here.
http://pastebin.com/tUpkM77G
I would appreciate it if you could review that and tell me anything I have wrong (terminology too), as I appreciate the chance to learn when I can.
This is a great answer so I'll set it as accepted.

Comment: Just an update.. I've noticed that the clicking of buttons gets slow when I'm using an image for the buttons. This is how I'm doing it:
`ControlPaint.DrawButton(e.Graphics, mines[x, y].Bounds, ButtonState.Normal);`
`e.Graphics.DrawImage(mineImage, mines[x, y].Bounds);`
I think I need a faster way of getting the button clicks as opposed to going through each element of the array until I get to where I clicked. It might also be because of the format of the image. I'll try PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb if I can. Can you give any suggestions for the clicking algorithm?

Comment: @Anteara Format32bppPArgb is the fastest format in GDI+.  It shouldn't be that slow though, since I'm assuming it's a small image.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put in to this answer; and it fulfils my requirements superbly. However implementing this would require rewriting of almost all of my code. (I was running my tests with this on a different, independent project). However since it is a clever way of doing what I need, when I'm done with my game I will probably edit it to implement this. Henceforth I will give you my bounty when the timer is done :).

Answer (score 2):

hide `minesPanel`, paint your buttons, show `minesPanel`?

Comment: well I added ``minesPanel.Hide()`` before ``SuspendLayout`` and ``minesPanel.Show()`` after ``ResumeLayout``, and also the other way around, but neither combination showed a change.
Edit: If I hide minesPanel, and then manually call ``minesPanel.Show()`` after all intensive work is done by clicking on a button on my form, it does load much nicer, but still flickers.