# ListView is not scrolling in windows form

Tags: c#, listview, windows-forms-designer

I am creating a windows form with a listview. The listview contains multiple buttons. But the listview only shows some of them. How can I make the listview scrollable so that I can see all the buttons. Here is my code

```
private void checkProgress_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        int totalRows = 5;
        int totalCols = 5;

        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
        int startX = 0;
        int startY = 0;

        //creating the buttons
        for(int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < totalCols; j++)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(startX, startY);
                b.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
                b.Name = "r" + i + "c" + j;
                startX += 20;
                this.listView1.Controls.Add(b);
            }
            startX = 0;
            startY += 400;

        }            
           //Dummy column
            ColumnHeader header = new ColumnHeader();
            header.Text = "";
            header.Name = "col1";
            listView1.Columns.Add(header);
    }
```

This code is written inside the load function of the windows form.

Comment: The listview is not in any container

Comment: The ListView is not an appropriate container control.  Don't add buttons to it.

Comment: @LarsTech what should I use instead?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you are just adding buttons, use a FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: @LarsTech something like the minesweeper game (there would be around 10k buttons)

Comment: Good god no.  One panel, you draw the grid on it in the paint event.  Handle mouse down events to figure out which "cell" the user is clicking on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172444/discussion-between-justcurious-and-larstech).

Comment: See [Foreach loop to create 100 buttons, painting all buttons at same time as to prevent flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13219154/719186)