# How to reproduce a friendly loop for MouseDown event c#

Tags: c#

I have problem when i try to set base.OnMouseDown(e) on MouseDown event or another one it's crashing for the reason `System.StackOverflowException: 'An exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'` and in exception details i get **[The above 2 frame(s) have been repeated 6289 times]**, I want to get a part of this (only for click on painted button) [Foreach loop to create 100 buttons, painting all buttons at same time as to prevent flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194674/foreach-loop-to-create-100-buttons-painting-all-buttons-at-same-time-as-to-prev) but i don't know how to fix this.

```
    private void Dashboard_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < alts; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 1; ++x)
            {
                if (new Rectangle(735, alts_Y + 5, 45, 15).Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    this.Invalidate();
                }
                alts_Y += 72;
            }
        }
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're messing up an event handler (your method `Dashboard_MouseDown()`) with triggering the event here (by calling `OnMouseDown()`).

`OnMouseDown()` triggers your event handler `Dashboard_MouseDown()`. Calling `OnMouseDown()` executes `Dashboard_MouseDown()`. That leads to an infinite loop and result in a StackOverflowException.

In the example you linked, the protected `OnMouseDown()` method is overridden and needs to call the `base.OnMouseDown()` to trigger the registered events.

If you override the base class you need to override the protected `OnMouseDown()`. If you want to register to the event use your `Dashboard_MouseDown()` but without the call of `base.OnMouseDown()`.